# Is there a way to create a two part profile?

Tags: wordpress, profile

I am trying to make a profile that based on a previous selected it would either lead you to another part of a profile. Like if you select an option on the first part of the profile and then you could hit another button to take you to the second part of the profile.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use jQuery to handle selection on first profile then show/hide base class of second profile. Also you would need jQuery to handle validation of second profile as the fields may or may not be required based on selection of first profile fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal than i believe you can split the profile into multiple forms by using webform.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: The question is tagged as Wordpress which is why i removed my original answer along these lines, but agree that other folk may get to this question who are using Drupal and hence this answer is helpful to them, but not to the OP.